# After switch_db, the file is saved in the default db

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongoengine

I am new to mongoengine and am trying to save test data and test result files into two different databases. Here's the sample code,

**datadb.py**

```
from mongoengine import *
from smartserver.config import MONGODB_URI, MONGODB_PORT

class Cases(Document):
    casename = StringField()
    meta = {
    'collection': 'Cases'
    }

class Files(Document):
    data = FileField()
    meta = {
    'collection': 'Files',
    'db-alias': 'smartFiles'
    }

class Connector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connect('smartServer', alias='default', host=MONGODB_URI, port=MONGODB_PORT)
        connect('smartFiles', alias='smartFiles', host=MONGODB_URI, port=MONGODB_PORT)

Connector()
```

**twoDB.py**

```
import datadb
from mongoengine.context_managers import switch_db

def test():
    case = datadb.Cases(casename='test')
    case.save()
    with switch_db(datadb.Files, 'smartFiles') as Files:
        f = open('app.py', 'rb')
        newfile = Files()
        newfile.data.new_file()
        newfile.data.write(f.read())
        newfile.data.close()
        f.close()
        newfile.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Somehow after executed twoDB.py, 'case' was saved into smartServer and 'newfile' into smartFiles but I could see fs.files and fs.chunks was generated in smartServer too.
Does this means that the file itself is saved into smartServer? If yes, can anyone point out where I am wrong?

Thanks,
Ethan.

Comment: I just went through the docs again and realized that I should specify db_alias of the FileField and it seems working for me now....

Since I am new here, I can not answer my own question, just comments...  Thanks,Ethan

Comment: You have to wait 1 day, then you should be able to answer your own question, once you've reached more than 15 reputation (I believe).

Comment: Aren't you already specifying the alias in your code sample inside of switch_db?

Comment: After using the `meta = {'db_alias': 'smartFiles'}` on model class, then what is the need to use `switch_db`? It will obviously store to smartFiles alias only, right?. Please comment if i am wrong